# Getting Cannot read property 'polyfillWrapFlushCallback' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-cli, server-side-rendering, web-component, angular-universal

Using a Polymer Ui Library whichs uses custom webcomponenets, when i am using this with Angular universal getting below error on build.

[image]

Version:
@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.8.0"
Angular : 11.x
@polymer/polymer": "^3.5.1"

Want to run polymer UI in angular ssr without issues